# Magento how do I override/alter template/payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml file

Tags: magento-1.7

I need to add some text to this file [`template/payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml`], for a particular store within clients' magento site.  When I make a change to the purchaseorder.phtml file, it changes the text on all the stores.  So I need to somehow customize this for one store in particular.

I have read comments on several sites, some mention changing the local.xml, change the config.xml, make changes in admin panel, but this such a small change, I don't want to disrupt anything by going overboard.

I need to extend the functionality on the backend so this change can be made for a particular store or stores. the sites has five stores built into the one install and for now I need to make the above change to just one store.

I think I need to somehow add a PO field Heading and an "Additional Text" option to the Purchase order section in image two.  is this correct, if so how do I do this?

Could someone point me in the right direction to making this type of change please.

**Note**: I **can't** do the create directory structure, copy files, change needed files option

This is magento 1.7

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy purchaseorder.phtml file from base/default directory then paste it in your current template. Now you can alter content of it purchaseorder.phtml in your current directory, it wont affect the base file.Like below,

Copy from

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml

Paste to

app/design/frontend/base/current_theme/template/payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml

When you override a section, the folder structure should resemble the default template folder structure like current_theme/template/form/ **payment/purchaseorder.phtml** .
sorry for bad english.

Comment: You english is just fine.  Now I use to do exactly as you mentioned above, but a new template was added to this particular store  and structured changed so instead of duplication the directories as I once did, I have to extend the functionality by adjusting the config.xml. file.